# Extend home without unallocated space. With swap or ntfs

Tags: 14.04, ntfs, home-directory, swap, unallocated

I've just installed (some months ago) Ubuntu 14.04 on my Asus laptop. I followed a specific guide on partitions and thought everything was ok. But, beeing pretty new at this I probably made some mistake doing my partitions and now I have a nice mess.

I left 46.5 Gb for /, then 15 Gb for /home, and then 123 Gb for swap. It appears (have a look on the image of my gparted) that I also left 542 Gb for ntfs Data and 15 Gb for ntfs Restore (and don't really know if those need so much space). Also, I don't have any unallocated space and I don't know if this is good or really bad.

My question is: I don't have enough space in my `/home` partition (it is already 98% full) and I'd like to know how to extend it without any - apparently - unallocated space. Can I take some space from the swap or the NTFS partitions? How? I think I left them too much space..

[image: Gparted image]

Comment: 123GB for swap is unnecessary https://help.ubuntu.com/community/SwapFaq

Comment: The recommandation for the swap size is your RAM x2. For example: If you have 3Gb of RAM, put 6Gb for the swap

Answer (score 1):

It's barely possible what you want to achieve and not worth effort.

In your case, I would consider mounting NTFS partition in Linux, so that its content would be visible under some folder on linux, like /home//Desktop/NTFS.
This Ubuntu page might be valuable for you to read and follow:

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/MountingWindowsPartitions